# Названия коктейлей — в кавычках и с прописной?

Tags: прописная-строчная, кавычки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как писать названия коктейлей, например, "Маргариты"?
В кавычках и с прописной? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

199. Торговые названия продуктовых, парфюмерных и т. п. товаров, табачных изделий, марочных вин и других напитков заключаются в кавычки и пишутся с прописной буквы, напр.: сыр «Российский», колбаса «Докторская», конфеты «Ромашка», торт «Юбилейный», шоколад «Вдохновение», мыло «Детское», сигареты «Мальборо», вина «Солнечная долина», «Бычья кровь», «Монастырская изба», портвейн «Айгешат», напиток «Фанта».

Примечание. Названия сортов вин, минеральных вод и др. напитков, ставшие именами нарицательными, пишутся без кавычек со строчной **буквы, напр.: портвейн, шампанское, мадера, кагор, рислинг, кока-кола, ессентуки-17. Так же пишутся названия продуктовых и др. товаров в бытовом употреблении, напр.: Мы купили пошехонский сыр, любительскую колбасу и фанту.**

**Академический справочник.**

*Так что писать с прописной или со строчной, зависит от того, в каком значении вы употребляете данное название. Если в бытовом - со строчной, если в качестве торговой марки - с прописной.*